# Polar plot with cartesian values, lack of angular precision in the integrated arctan2 calculation?

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

I noticed that for values close to 0° and 180° the angular values dramatically changes if the values are imported from cartesian data. Here the code (with cartesian coordinates plotted in polar with data cs=cart and the same coordinates in polar coordinates obtained with arctan2 Matlab function) and illustration:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
    visualization depends on=x \as \pgfplotspointx,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.style={
        %font=\small,
        rotate=\pgfplotspointx,
        append after command={
            node [
                anchor=south,
                %font=\small,
                rotate=\pgfplotspointx,
                shift={(axis direction cs:0,(12.75-\pgfplotspointmeta))}
            ] {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointx}^\circ$}
        }
    },
width=7\textwidth,
xmin=-2,xmax=1, ymin=12, ymax=16,
title=artctan2 precision problem,
grid=both,
minor x tick num={4}, 
minor y tick num={1},
]
\addplot+[polar comb, data cs=cart, mark size=1, mark=asterisk, color=blue, dashed] table {
14.370195   -0.304948
14.370195   -0.304948

}; 
\addplot+[polar comb, mark size=1, mark=asterisk, color=green, solid] table {-1.215683667   14.37343027
-1.215683667    14.37343027
}; 
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Has anyone meet this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes this is known and there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: @percusse: Hm, but `\pgfmathparse{atan2(14.37,-0.304948)}
\pgfmathresult` gives the (almost) correct result of `-1.20`. Maybe there's something else at play in the conversion from cartesian to polar coordinates in PGFPlots?

Comment: @Jake The conversion doesn't use it I think. I had a similar problem before and I guess we need to dive into polar code. Maybe I should say *not much without hacking into the code*. I think somewhere in the drawing fpu is turned off.

Comment: Thank you for your fast comments. Thus, I will directly manipulate polar coordinates instead of using data cs =cart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs to be repaired in `pgfplots`, I accept this question as bug report.

---

Details:

The routine `pgfplotsmathcarttopol` does not make use of `atan2` - instead, it computes the angle "manually", apparently with less precision.

add

```
\pgfplotsmathcarttopol{14.370195}{-0.304948}\angle\radius

angle = \angle; radius = \radius
```

to see that this is, indeed, the root cause.

Steps to be done would be to write an implementation (or adapter) for `atan2` for the floating point unit of PGF and to use that one in `pgfplotsmathcarttopol`.

I will take a note for the todo list of `pgfplots` (no need to file a separate bug report).

Comment: OK. Thank you for your fast answer. I leave it like this (no bug report).

Comment: Solution has been integrated and will become part of pgfplots 1.12 .

Answer (score 3):

A solution with PSTricks. Run it with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(33,-2)(48,1.1)
\psset{runit=3}\uput[0](16;0){0}
\psarcn(0,0){12}{1}{-2}\psarcn(0,0){16}{1}{-2}
\psline(12;1)(16;1)\psline(12;-2)(16;-2)
\multido{\rA=12.25+0.25}{15}{\psarcn[linecolor=black!15](0,0){\rA}{1}{-2}}
\psline[linecolor=black!15](12;0)(16;0)\psline[linecolor=black!15](12;-1)(16;-1)
\multido{\rA=12.0+0.5}{9}{\uput[-90](\rA;-2.5){\rA}}
\psline[linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed]{-*}(12;-0.54)(14.37;-0.54)
\psline[linecolor=green]{-*}(12;-1.22)(14.37;-1.22)
\uput[90](12.75;-0.54){\blue$-0.54^\circ$}\uput[90](12.75;-1.22){\green$-1.22^\circ$}
\uput[90](14.37;-0.54){\blue$14.37$}\uput[90](14.37;-1.22){\green$14.37$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to be a complete different package no? I am actually a new user of pgfplots so maybe I don't got all the tricks now! I will study your approach ;-)

Comment: Yes, it does all calculations with PostScript, a complete programming language.